# Applying annotations to fields inherited from @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, annotations, mappedsuperclass

Has:

```
@MappedSuperclass
class Superclass {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name="field")
    private long field;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
class Subclass extends Superclass {

}
```

How to annotate inherited id with @GeneratedValue and field with @Index within Subclass?

Comment: any new word on this, is this still true for the current version of hibernate?

Answer (score 5):

> How to annotate inherited id with @GeneratedValue and field with @Index within Subclass?

AFAIK, you can't. What you can do is overriding attributes and associations (i.e. change the column or join column) using the `AttributeOverride` and `AssociationOverride` annotations. But you can't do exactly what you're asking.

For the `GeneratedValue`, consider using XML mapping to override the strategy if you don't want to declare it in the mapped superclass.

For the `Index` (which is not a standard annotation by the way), did you actually try to declare it at the table level using Hibernate's `Table` annotation instead (I'm assuming you're using Hibernate)?

> ```
> @Table(appliesTo="tableName", indexes = { @Index(name="index1", columnNames=
>     {"column1", "column2"} ) } )
> ```
>
> creates the defined indexes on the
>   columns of table tableName.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 2.1.9.2 "Mapped Superclasses"
  - Section 9.1.10 "AttributeOverride Annotation"
  - Section 9.1.11 "AttributeOverrides Annotation"
  - Section 9.1.12 "AssociationOverride Annotation"
  - Section 9.1.13 "AssociationOverrides Annotation"
- Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide

  - [2.4. Hibernate Annotation Extensions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec)
  - [Chapter 3. Overriding metadata through XML](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#xml-overriding)

Answer (score 1):

As for `@GeneratedValue`, it is possible to do like this:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
class Superclass {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_generator")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "field")
    private long field;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_generator", sequenceName = "id_seq")
class Subclass extends Superclass {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this if you apply the annotations to the accessor methods instead. (I haven't tried this, so I can't guarantee that it'll work.)

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Superclass {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

.

```
@Entity
public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    @GeneratedValue
    public long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else searches for this, I used the following code which adds in some overhead, but for processing Field annotations only shouldn't add that much:

```
    private List<Field> getAllFields() {
    List<Field> fieldList = new ArrayList<Field>();

    // Add all fields from the current class
    fieldList.addAll(Arrays.asList(mElement.getClass().getDeclaredFields()));

    // Use an index to iterate over mElement's parent types
    Class clazz = mElement.getClass();

    // Get any fields from the parent class(es)
    while (clazz.getSuperclass() != null) {
        fieldList.addAll(Arrays.asList(clazz.getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields()));
        // Set it to that parent class
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }

    return fieldList;
}
```

The returned list would contain all fields for all parent and child classes with `mElement` being the object you are searching for annotations from. Hope this helps.